# Timezone change when writing timestamp field from Spark SQL to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

My Spark dataframe has some timestamp fields with UTC timezone:

```
2010-06-06 21:29:07.730
```

However, after writing to Hive, the field in the Hive table has local time zone (PST).

```
2010-06-06 14:29:07.730
```

Is this the bug of Spark or Hive? And how can I avoid this timezone change?

Thanks